# finding a pattern in text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a *text file*, say

```
1: 0,0,0,122
2: 2,0,3,333
3: 0,0,0,23
```

and so on.
i need to find "0,0,0" pattern in the text file
 and print all lines except the one containing the given pattern.
 please can anyone tell me the **code** for this in **python**.

Comment: I can help you but I won't solve this for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A robust way would be something like:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'0\s*,0\s*,0\s*')
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
            if pattern.search(line):
                    print line
```

In this way if you have a line that has some space it's skipped(e.g. "0, 0,0" instead of "0,0,0").

But if you're sure that the will be no such thing, or if you want to match exactly "0,0,0"[no spaces], than you can avoid using the `re` module and just use the `in` operator:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
            if '0,0,0' not in line:
                    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in textfile.split('\n'):
    if '0,0,0' not in line:
        print line
```

Comment: This assumes that the whole file is in memory (in `textfile`). Using the iterator approach `for line in file` is more efficient and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [context manager](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open the file. Iterate through the file line by line. If your pattern does not occur in the line, print the line:

```
filename = 'textfile.txt'
pattern = '0,0,0'

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if pattern not in line:
            print line
```

Untested, but should work.